# Iterate all files in a folder and delete specific lines

Tags: java

I have a folder with multiple txt files that I need to edit. Each file contains multiple lines. Some lines start with 0, some don't. The file is like this:

```
74 0.734047 0.308853 0.036312 0.075260 
0 0.581609 0.715352 0.141344 0.561774 
0 0.730945 0.765627 0.088922 0.468746 
69 0.146391 0.866284 0.217000 0.240459 
26 0.746844 0.768563 0.040094 0.120306
```

What I want to do is to keep all the lines that start with 0, and delete the rest of lines. If a file has no lines that start with 0, I want to delete the whole file. In the example above, I want to modify the file to be like this:

```
0 0.581609 0.715352 0.141344 0.561774 
0 0.730945 0.765627 0.088922 0.468746
```

Could anyone help me with the code snippet in Java?

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: 1) List all files of directory 2) Loop through files, read them line by line using any reader. 3) If line.indexOf("0 "==0), put then in list. 4) Rewrite the list data to file. 5) If list is empty, delete the file.